# KVO on Swift's computed properties

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, foundation, computed-properties

Is KVO on a computed property possible in Swift?

```
var width = 0
var height = 0

private var area : Double {
    get {
        return with * height
    }
}

self.addOberser(self, forKeyPath: "area", ......
```

Would a client code modifying the with or height trigger observeValueForKeyPath?

Just checking before engaging on a mayor class refactor. KVO's syntax being as annoying as it's is not worth even a playground if someone has an answer at hand. (I am assuming the answer is NO)

Comment: The KVO is all about the setter, where is your setter @dhomes ?

Comment: Have a look at [`RxSwift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift).

Comment: @Basheer_CAD that's the point! i'm referring can one observe a read-only computed property? would setting the width or height trigger a new area calculation? (would assume no, but maybe some fancy compiler ????)

Comment: @dfri, quite interesting! thanks a lot!

Comment: @dhomes take a look at Rob's answer it should be helpful

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That code won't work for two reasons:

1. You must add the `dynamic` attribute to the `area` property, as described in the section “Key-Value Observing” under [“Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns” in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6).
2. You must declare that `area` depends on `width` and `height` as described in [“Registering Dependent Keys” in the *Key-Value Observing Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html). (This applies to Objective-C and Swift.) And for this to work, you also have to add `dynamic` to `width` and `height`.

   (You could instead call `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` whenever `width` or `height` changes, but it's usually easier to just implement `keyPathsForValuesAffectingArea`.)

Thus:

```
import Foundation

class MyObject: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic var width: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var height: Double = 0

    @objc dynamic private var area: Double {
        return width * height
    }

    @objc class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingArea() -> Set<String> {
        return [ "width", "height" ]
    }

    func register() {
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "area", options: [ .old, .new ], context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("observed \(keyPath) \(change)")
    }
}

let object = MyObject()
object.register()
object.width = 20
object.height = 5
```

Output:

```
observed Optional("area") Optional([__C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: new): 0, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: kind): 1, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: old): 0])
observed Optional("area") Optional([__C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: new): 100, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: kind): 1, __C.NSKeyValueChangeKey(_rawValue: old): 0])
```

Comment: I believe according to those same documentation links, you are supposed to specify the context, no?

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to use a `context` for several reasons, but this answer wasn't about that part of KVO. Also, if you only inherit from `NSObject`, you don't need to use a `context` unless you want to, because `NSObject` doesn't register for any KVO notifications, so there's no possibility of conflicting with your superclass.

Comment: Good info! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

As @Rob stated in his answer, make `area` `dynamic` to be observed from objective-c

Now add `willSet { }` and `didSet { }` for `width` and `height` properties, 
inside `willSet` for both properties add this `self.willChangeValueForKey("area")`
and in `didSet` add `self.didChangeValueForKey("area");`

Now observers of `area` will be notified every time width or height change.

Note: this code is not tested, but I think it should do what expected

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do these days to avoid `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` with unchecked string property names is make the computed property `private(set)` and create a private `func` to update it.

```
import Foundation

class Foo: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic private(set) var area: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var width: Double = 0 { didSet { updateArea() } }
    @objc dynamic var height: Double = 0 { didSet { updateArea() } }

    private func updateArea() {
        area = width * height
    }
}
```