# Swift 3: Observing a read-only property

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So there's this class in SpriteKit:

```
open class SKNode : UIResponder, NSCopying, NSCoding, UIFocusItem {

    ...

    open var scene: SKScene? { get }

    ...
```

I would like to trigger some logic when the `scene` property becomes not nil.

This is what I tried:

```
class MyNode : SKNode {

    override var scene: SKScene? {
        didSet {
            if scene != nil {
                // my custom logic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error: `Cannot observe read-only property 'scene'; it can't change` which makes sense in theory.

In practice, the value of the property *does* change:

```
let node = SKNode()
print(node.scene?)  // nil

scene.addChild(node)
print(node.scene?)  // SKScene
```

Is there some black magic that I could use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is *computed*, the value changes but it is never set. It is calculated from other values.

Therefore it makes no sense to put a `didSet` there.

From [Read-Only Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259)

> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be set to a different value.

If we are speaking about `SKNode.scene`, it's probably just an accessor method to a private ivar `_scene`, or, it dynamically goes up the tree and returns the root.

Since it is an Obj-C class, you can probably use KVO to observe the value, if you really really need it.

Comment: Found this question on using KVO for computed properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555492/kvo-on-swifts-computed-properties

Comment: The same error shows for `private(set)` properties.